# "Your" bounty has been completed

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications

[image]

I didn't put up the bounty. [Won't did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/160338/revisions).

- Why do I need to be notified of the bounty getting completed? There is no corresponding notification for "your question has been bountied by someone else"
- If I *do* need to be notified, for some reason, then shouldn't the text read "The bounty on your question X has completed."?

It seems like the system is assuming that the owner of a question bounty is the asker here :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in a deploy about 20 hours ago.

You're guess was correct, the messaging code was using `question.Owner` incorrectly.